# Why are there two articles here?

Tags: dative, article, accusative

> Mit den Französischbüchern in **der einen** Hand und dem Kaffee in der anderen Hand öffnet sie die Tür des Lehrerzimmers und...

Why are there the two boldfaced articles here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not an article in this case, it's a numeral meaning "*one*":

> ... in *one* hand ... in *another* hand

Comment: So why does it have `en` in `einen`?

Comment: For the same reason there is "-en" in "anderen" - because it’s declined.